# Undefined variable in lambda function

Tags: python, pyspark, pylint

I have the code :

```
from functools import reduce

public_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
filepath = '/path/to/file/'

rdd = sc.textFile(
    filepath
)

new_rdd = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.filter(
        lambda x: b not in x
    ),
    public_ids,
    rdd
)
```

This code is suppose to filter lines in a rdd according to a list of ids. The rdd is created from files located in filepath using spark context sc's textFile method.

This code works fine, but pylint raises the error :

> E: Undefined variable 'b' (undefined-variable)

I believe the way I coded it is not the proper way. How can I change it so pylint does not raise the error again ? Or is it just a structure that `pylint` does not recognize properly ?

Comment: To answer the spirit of your question, perhaps you can try actually naming your functions instead of nesting the lambdas: `def func(a, b): return a.filter(lambda x: b not in x)`.  And then call `reduce(func, ...)` instead.  I'm guessing it had to do with scoping within anonymous functions, so naming it *might* help.

Comment: I thought that could be the issue indeed, but creating a function used only once is against my religion.

Comment: *From my point of view, disposable named functions are evil!* Well then you're lost! ...sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely it's a bug in pylint.

Here is a [similar bug report](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/760) from 2 years ago

> `foo = lambda x: lambda: x + 1 print(foo(1)())`
>
> correctly prints 2 when run, but pylint incorrectly reports
>
> `E:  1,24: Undefined variable 'x' (undefined-variable)`
>
> This is a regression from pylint 1.4.x.

And here is a [recent issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2595) reporting the same issue on 11/14/2018

> The issue has been reported at #760 and fixed by #2274. However, the
>   fix is merged only into pylint 2.x which supports only python >= 3.4
>   leaving us with the bug unresolved in the pylint 1.x series for python
>   2.

## EDIT

Looks like your false positive might be slightly different than the issue above, nevertheless, I would still consider this a bug.

I would try creating an issue on their repo and see what happens 
(if you decide to do so, please post link in comments so we can follow it.)